# HTML multiple onclick events not occurring when I want

Tags: javascript, html

When the user clicks read more, I want the page to change to the new page (News.html) and then scroll down a specific amount so that it lines up with the article, but what's happening is that when you click read more, the page lowers a specific amount and then changes to the top of the news.html page

```
<article>
     <h3>Is Joe Hart right for Torino?</h3>
     <img src = "News_Images/Joe_Hart_Torino.jpg" alt = "Joe" width="225" height="150">
     <button class = "btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick ="Change(); scrollWin();">
           <p>Read</p>
     </button>             
</article>

<script>
    function Change(){
        document.location.href = "News.html";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function scrollWin() {
        window.scrollBy(100, 175);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When you change the page .... everything is lost. You can't redirect, and then keep executing javascript like you didn't redirect.

Comment: Is there any way for me to execute the function that scrolls down then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) for instance #content. Put in appropriate place on the 
 News.html page and update your function to something like

```
function Change(){
    document.location.href = "News.html#content";
}
```

Btw when you click only one onclick event occurs it's not supposed to occur multiple events and in your case both functions are executed, just moving takes time and you see scrolling first. Using scroll with hardcoded value is not good idea, you'll need to update it every time you update content of News.html

```
**UPDATE**
```

procrastinator is right, see comment below, just use anchor if it's applicable for you.

Comment: Fragment is probably the best way, but a plain anchor instead of js would be even better :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you move to another page, javascript reloads and does not continue execution from where you left off.

A solution to your problem could be using a request parameter.

Change your function to this:

```
function Change(){
    document.location.href = "News.html?scroll=yes";
}
```

And in your News.html page, add this code to the page's `onload` event:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var param = url.searchParams.get("scroll");

if (param == "yes")
   window.scrollBy(100, 175);
```

Comment: At first I had thought about the same solution but then I realized bicycle for that case had been invented :) But instead hardcoded values I thought to use element position on the page

Comment: @DanielGrankin Bicycle?

Comment: my bad, I think it's more known as Reinvent the wheel

Comment: @DanielGrankin I'm from Israel... Don't know these dev slang words. Sorry bro. I upvoted your answer since it's better than mine, but I'm gonna leave mine just in case somebody needs this type of solution in the future.